# How to reliably convince matplotlib to use PySide2 backend when running from Anaconda (Spyder)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda, qt5, pyside2

I am creating a PySide2 application which uses matplotlib. I am running this application from Spyder in an environment with PySide2 installed. This is causing the application to be run from the iPython console. Somewhere along the line, PyQt5 is imported, which I am attempting to purge in order to convince matplotlib that I really do want to use PySide2, NOT PyQt5. Something like following was working until very recently and I am not really sure why it has stopped, but safe to say this method is unreliable. How can I absolutely convince matplotlib that I am wanting PySide2?

I have tried setting the environment variable QT_API in the operating system (Windows 10), but in this case Spyder itself refuses to open.

```
import sys
import os

ps = list(filter(lambda x: 'PyQt5' in x, sys.modules))
for p in ps:
    print(f"purging module {p}")
    sys.modules.pop(p)
    
# matplotlib.__init__ uses this
os.environ["MPLBACKEND"] = "PySide2"

# matplotlib.backends.qt_compat uses this
os.environ["QT_API"] = "PySide2"

import PySide2.QtCore

assert "PyQt5.QtCore" not in sys.modules
assert "PySide2.QtCore" in sys.modules

# rcParams has the right idea
from matplotlib import rcParams
print(rcParams["backend"])

# qt_compat has the WRONG idea!
import matplotlib.backends.qt_compat as qt_compat
print(qt_compat.QT_API)

# The FigureCanvasWidget is of the wrong (PyQt5) type
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
import inspect
print(inspect.getmro(FigureCanvas))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, the reason that it stopped working was because I had set 'activate support' for Matplotlib graphics in the ipython tab under Spyder settings. After unchecking this, the above works.